# How do I add a Label Hint to Kartik DetailView

Tags: yii2

I'm using Kartik DetailView and would like to have a hint appear when the user hovers over the label (like the GII forms).  I've tried the following, but it does not work.

```
 $attributes = [
    [   'attribute'=>'name',
        'inputWidth'=>'50%',
    ],
    [   'attribute'=>'round_precision',
        'hint' => 'Specify the number of decimal digits after the decimal to round to.  Use a negative value to round the integer part of the number to the number of digits before the decimal. A value of 1 will round 1.855 to 1.7, and a value of -2 will round 1.855 1.86.  A value of -1 will round 17.6 to 18, and a value of -2 will round 17.6 to 20.',
        'inputWidth'=>'10%',
    ],
];
```

How do I get Gii-like hints in the Kartik DetailView Widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears GII is just using Bootstrap Popovers.  I followed the instructions on http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/664/activating-bootstrap-3-tooltips-popover-for-your-yii-site/ and then began creating labels with help popovers.

I created the following function to render the label.

```
 /**
 * Create a help popover to be shown on an input form.
 * @param $label string The label to display for the input.
 * @param $help string The help text to display.
 * @return string
 */
public static function renderLabelHelp($label, $help) {
    return Html::tag('span', $label, [
        'data-toggle'=>'popover',
        'data-trigger' => 'click hover',
        'data-placement' => 'auto right',
        'data-html' => 'true',    // allow html tags
        'data-title'=> 'Field Help',
        'data-content'=>$help,
        'style'=>'text-decoration: underline; cursor:help;'
    ]);
}
```

Then I call the function with something like this.

```
<?= Html::label(MyHelpers::renderLabelHelp(
    $model->getAttributeLabel('round_precision'),
    'Specify the number of decimal digits after the decimal to round to.<br>Use a negative value to round the integer part of the number to the number of digits before the decimal.<br>A value of 1 will round 1.855 to 1.7, and a value of -2 will round 1.855 1.86.  A value of -1 will round 17.6 to 18, and a value of -2 will round 17.6 to 20.'
) ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

in yii2 Model class have good method attributeHints()

```
/**
 * Returns the attribute hints.
 *
 * Attribute hints are mainly used for display purpose. For example, given an attribute
 * `isPublic`, we can declare a hint `Whether the post should be visible for not logged in users`,
 * which provides user-friendly description of the attribute meaning and can be displayed to end users.
 *
 * Unlike label hint will not be generated, if its explicit declaration is omitted.
 *
 * Note, in order to inherit hints defined in the parent class, a child class needs to
 * merge the parent hints with child hints using functions such as `array_merge()`.
 *
 * @return array attribute hints (name => hint)
 * @since 2.0.4
 */
public function attributeHints()
{
    return [];
}
```

you can use this

```
'hint' => $model->getAttributeHint('round_precision')
```